# Want to use ListView with multiple ImageButtons (so it's scrollable), how would I resize the buttons with code?

Tags: java, android

I want to have automatically resizing buttons to the screen size, it worked great, but since I need a ListView to make it scrollable it won't work anymore since it throws an exception

> Exception raised during rendering: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

This is the code I use currently to resize images (not sure if it's useful or not):

```
public void getScreenRes() {
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenwidth = display.widthPixels;
    int screenheight = display.heightPixels;
    double buttonheight = screenwidth / 2.66666667;
    int buttonheightint= (int) Math.round(buttonheight);
    ImageButton fbLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams fb = fbLogin.getLayoutParams();
    fb.width = screenwidth;
    fb.height = buttonheightint;
    fbLogin.setLayoutParams(fb);
    ImageButton instaLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.instagramLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams insta = instaLogin.getLayoutParams();
    insta.width = screenwidth;
    insta.height = buttonheightint;
    instaLogin.setLayoutParams(insta);
    ImageButton twitLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.twitterLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams twit = twitLogin.getLayoutParams();
    twit.width = screenwidth;
    twit.height = buttonheightint;
    twitLogin.setLayoutParams(twit);
    ImageButton redditLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redditLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams reddit = redditLogin.getLayoutParams();
    reddit.width = screenwidth;
    reddit.height = buttonheightint;
    redditLogin.setLayoutParams(reddit);
}
```

This is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.eren.valour.FirstTimeLogin">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/getStarted"
    android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:background="@drawable/facebook"
       android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
       android:onClick="facebookLogin"

       />
   <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram"
        android:layout_below="@+id/facebookLogin"
        android:id="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:onClick="instagramLogin"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/twitter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:id="@+id/twitterLogin"
        android:onClick="twitterLogin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/reddit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twitterLogin"
        android:id="@+id/redditLogin"
        android:onClick="redditLogin"
        />
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Listview or LinearLayout ?

Comment: I want it to be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You should create listview_row and fill listview with adapter(ArrayAdapter). If listview item are a lot of listview can be scrollable.

listview_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_sign_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook"
        android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
        android:onClick="facebookLogin" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram"
        android:layout_below="@+id/facebookLogin"
        android:id="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:onClick="instagramLogin" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/twitter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:id="@+id/twitterLogin"
        android:onClick="twitterLogin" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/reddit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twitterLogin"
        android:id="@+id/redditLogin"
        android:onClick="redditLogin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eren.valour.FirstTimeLogin"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/getStarted"
        android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```